# How do I include an external library in a short Python script without using Pip?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to make my small Python very portable so a few of my friends can simply download it and run it easily. My script uses [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.org) (a Reddit API wrapper in Python) to facilitate some calls at one point, but everything I search ends up recommending installing these third-party libraries through Pip or a similar package installer of sorts.

Is there a way to just download a library like PRAW, throw it in the same folder as the main script and simply `import` it? How would I go about doing this so as to not require my friends to have to install Pip?

Comment: First of All, Why not to use pip? What's the problem with that?

Comment: Then, I think it really depends on that library. Some need to compile some sorts of code and some need to setup environment on that system. That's what setup.py files do.